# Como fazer um background, com um conjunto de imagens?

Tags: css

Bom, a minha pergunta é a seguinte, como poderei fazer um background de uma div no css, com um conjunto de imagens e não apenas com 1 só?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta inserir outras imagens e definir o posicionamento individual. Veja o exemplo:

```css
.teste{
 
  min-width:250px;
  min-height:250px;
  background:#ff0000;
  background-image:url('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif'),
 url('http://www.css3.info/wp-content/themes/new_css3/img/sheep.png');
 background-position: center top, left top;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="teste">
 </div>
```

Documentação: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/